# How will I be able to obtain the coroutine's name in the targetted coroutine?

Tags: lua, minecraft-forge

I want something like this:

```lua
local co1 = coroutine.create(function()
    local evt, _, _, nm, arg1 = event.pull("thread_msg", 2)
    -- Pull a "thread_msg" event.

    if(nm == coroutine_name)then
        print(evt, arg1) -- Print the event name and the argument sent by "thread_msg"
    end
end)

coroutine.resume(co1)
event.push("thread_msg", "co1", "") -- Sends a message to the coroutine
```

I need the coroutine's name. "thread_msg" event sends to all of the running coroutines, same for coroutine.send. I need to obtain the name of coroutine inside the coroutine.

Working with opencomputers with mc version 1.12.2 forge.
The architecture of the CPU is lua 5.3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `load()` the coroutine' code.
Because with `load()` you can give functions a name that will be stored in `source` of `debug.getinfo()`' table.
This `source` will also be used if an error occurs in the coroutine/function traceback.
I give you a basic example for the Lua interactive console with the easy/lazy `coroutine.wrap()` function to construct the coroutine function...

```
$ /usr/bin/lua
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> code={}
> run={}
> code.co=[[return coroutine.wrap(function(...)
>> local args={...} -- args is holding arguments
>> args[0]=debug.getinfo(1).source -- Name given by load(textcode,'Name')
>> print(args[0],'Going to yielding now')
>> coroutine.yield(args)
>> args=[0]=debug.getinfo(1).source -- Update args[0] here if called more coroutines in loop
>> print('Going to end:',args[0])
>> print(args[0],'Coroutine goes dead now')
>> return args
>> end)]]
> run[1]=load(code.co,'Megacoroutine')()
> run[1]()
Megacoroutine   Going to yielding now
table: 0x565e2890
> run[1]()
Going to end:   Megacoroutine
Megacoroutine   Coroutine goes dead now
table: 0x565e2890
> run[1]()
stdin:1: cannot resume dead coroutine
stack traceback:
    [C]: in field '?'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
>
```

EDIT: args has to be local (corrected)

Comment: Thanks, this will help me make my threading module for the operating system. I will publish it on github soon. I am making this OS because I want a linux-like system and also the regular editor is so trash.

Comment: What is "mode" used for in load?

Comment: The "mode" binary ("b") is not possible with a coroutine function ( I tryed and that throws an error ). ```code.co``` is "t" (text chunk) and the default for mode is "bt" so ```load()``` checks ```code.co``` is "text" or "binary" chunk. But its OK when using explizit "t" as "mode" for ```code.co```. A binary chunk is produced with ```string.dump()``` with a function as argument.

Comment: An function style error i have to correct is to make args local in the coroutine else every new created (with load(code.co,'newname') ) coroutine override global args whats probably unwanted.

Comment: It's not a ploblem, I already know but thank you anyway, all I do sometimes is chug that sweet juicy code and *paste* it inside my programs which also means I don't read the code so yea I have to debug for several hours to get it fixed :P.

But don't call me a chugger please I don't deserve to go to chug jail I promise I don't steal a lot of code :,^(

Comment: Yeah you earned the Chuggy Batch ;-P - And keep in mind above code' play without args table constructed with and from the three dots. That table holding the arguments from first coroutine call you need for futher things. I suggest that ```args[0]``` is holding ```debug.getinfo(1).source``` like in ```C``` and other languages. Then you wouldnt copy everytime the longer ```debug.getgetinfo(1).source``` where you want it. Moment i put it in above code :-)